# Put coordinates of tiles only in extremes of the map (API v3 Google Maps)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, coordinates

I want to put the coordinates of tiles only in the extremes of the map, right now I have the coordinates in all map.

[image]

This is my code:

```
 CoordMapType.prototype.getTile = function(coord, zoom, ownerDocument) {

      var div = ownerDocument.createElement('div');

      div.innerHTML = '<p style="color: #000000;background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.85); width:22%; font-weight: bold;">'+coord+'</p>';
        div.style.color ='#FFFFFF';
      div.style.width = this.tileSize.width + 'px';
      div.style.height = this.tileSize.height + 'px';
      div.style.fontSize = '10px';
      div.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
      div.style.borderWidth = '1px';
      div.style.borderColor = '#AAAAAA';
      return div;
    };
```

Comment: If you want them referenced to the viewport of the map, you should put them on the map, not the tiles.

Comment: Thanks, you were right  and i forgot say thanks. You can the result here if you want.  http://herrero.ninja/TFG/index.html